# Create a Fixed URL

Tags: asp.net

I have a web application that have many pages and folders, I want to make the URL to this website fixed for all pages, example: if the web site is 
www.testwebsite.com/home.aspx when I redirect to login.aspx (for example) I want the URL to be 
www.testwebsite.com/home.aspx without any changes and so on

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You want redirects to `login.aspx` to go to `home.aspx`? Really?

Comment: no I just want to create a fake URL I'll be on Login.aspx, but I want the URL to be Home.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can do a `Server.Transfer`, instead of Response.Redirect from home.aspx to login.aspx. This will keep the url as home.aspx

**Response.Redirect** : Tells the browser to go and visit another url. So there is a response coming back to browser and then browser is navigating to the new page. So its like a new request now. You will see the new page url in your address bar.

**Server.Transfer** : there will not be any "Redirect" response coming back to browser. The Server itself change the destination page. So the client browser does not know that its another page. So the url will not be changed.The Transfer method preserves the QueryString and Form collections.

Comment: yeah you are right but this will keep the Home.aspx stored on memory